# Add option to dropdownlist in razor asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "Id", "Name"),"Select category", new { @class = "form-select mt-3" })
```

I want to add a value of null to "Select category", specifically in razor, not in the controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try it like that:

```
<select asp-for="YourProperty">
<option value="" selected>Select category</option>
@foreach(var item in YourList){
    <option value="@item.Id">@item.YourValue</option>
}
</select>
```